# Maximum filename length on Blackberry

Tags: file, blackberry, filesystems, maxlength

Is there a maximum filename length (or equivalent to MAX_PATH) on the BlackBerry operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 4.5/4.6/4.7 (found out by experiment):

- **SDCard** path can't be longer than 263 chars
- **store** path max is 269 chars

Answer (score 2):

The maximum filename length is not exposed.  The best you can do is to catch FileIOException and add handling for error code FileIOException.FILE_NAME_TOO_LONG.